# How to make Lanterns rising in sky form an infinity logo

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I am working on a Live action CGI shot for Diwali where we see sky lanterns rising in the sky and then few of those lanterns starts to form the shape of infinity. Any ideas or tips on how to form the infinity sign with lanterns. Also, i have made lanterns rising animation with geometry nodes. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this node setup, which "just" moves them from a volume cube to a bezier-infinite symbol.

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, this was really helpful, Can you please also guide me on how to set this up so that only few lanterns form the sign, rest keep rising towards the sky ?